# Form data is empty after sending it with Axios

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios, multipartform-data

I'm sending an `FormData` from a `VueJS` application using `Axios`. The problem is that when I output the `FormData` it's empty. I've used the same method before when sending a file (I'm not sending a file now) and then the `FormData` shows the right data that I've append to it. The data I'm appending is of the type string.

> Client Side

```
onUpload(): void {
      const fd = new FormData();
      fd.append("id", this.chosenRoute.id);
      fd.append("name", this.routeName);
      fd.append("description", this.routeDescription);
      fd.append("activity", this.activity);
      fd.append("preamble", this.preamble);
      axios.post('http://localhost:8080/editRoute', fd, {
      onUploadProgress: uploadEvent => {
        console.log('Upload Progress' + Math.round(uploadEvent.loaded / uploadEvent.total) * 100 + " %");
      }
    }).then(
      res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

> Server Side

```
app.post('/editRoute', function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    const routeId = req.body.id;
    console.log(routeId);
    Route.findById(routeId, (err, route) => {
        res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        route.update(req.body);
    });
});
```

Comment: Not too familiar with vue.js / axios, but it could be a content-type issue. Content type is different when sending a file.

Comment: @JM-AGMS Do you know if I could send it as something else? I've tried sending it as a JSON-string but it gives me problems too

Comment: @MrAleister I'm not sending a file this time. It's only strings.

Comment: @M.H it think you should set `let fd = new FormData()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From axios documentation:

> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON.

So, you can't just pass a JS `FormData` object straight to the options of an `axios` call. If you must use `FormData`, see recommended methods here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format

However, if, as you mention above, but what looks like key/value pairs, don't use `FormData` at all, but a regular JavaScript Object.

```
const body = {
    "id": this.chosenRoute.id.
    "name": this.routeName,
    "description": this.routeDescription,
    "activity": this.activity,
    "preamble": this.preamble
}

axios.post('http://localhost:8080/editRoute', body, ...
```

Comment: What if I actually want to send files? URLSearchParams doesn´t seems like a valid solution. So, there´s a way to send files from axios in browser to a nodeJs server?

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you supposed to use **.set()** not .append() for regular fields, I thought you used .append() for files only?

I also suggest getting to grips with native JSON for form data handling as the other answer mentions, It is a lot simpler, cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from v0.27.0, Axios supports automatic object serialization to a FormData object if the request Content-Type header is set to multipart/form-data.
see the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#formdata)!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using axios in express (don't know if that matters). The body of the request sent remained empty. What helped in my case was to update Axios to the latest version, from `0.27.2` to `1.5.1`.